# Use element.getBoundingClientRect() in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

If I find an element in lightning using `document.getElementById('myId')`, I can call the `getBoundingClientRect` and is working fine.
But if I try to get the element using `component.find('myAuraId)`, `getBoundingClientRect()` is not defined for that element.

How is possible call `getBoundigClientRect` using aura `find()` method? Do you know some alternatives to `getBoundingClientRect` in lightning?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using getBoundingClientRect  on init?

Comment: No, I'm calling getBoundinClientReact() when the user scrolls. Also component.find('myAuraId) returns the element but it hasn't the getBoundingClientRect function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use

> component.find('myAuraId).getElement().getBoundingClientRect()

instead of

> component.find('myAuraId).getBoundingClientRect()